# Modifying the background on a :before style in Javascript. (No libraries)

Tags: javascript, css

In my application I am making use of the `:before` for an image background. This is to "sharpen" the image that's in the container, as it's using a `-webkit-filter: blur()`.

The issue is that I cannot find a way to change the `:before` style using Javascript. I need to change the background image to be whatever the foreground image is.

Example CSS:

```
#image-container:before {
    background: url(img.png);
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    height: 40%;
}

#image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 58%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.blur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Inside the image container I have the following code:

```
<div id="image-container">
    <img class="blur" src="img.png" width="100%" height="100%">
</div>
```

The issue is that the img source is actually coming in from my server, so I need the background to match up with the image so the edges (from the blur) don't look sloppy and conflicted.

So the question here is, how can I change the `background: url()` value on the `#image-container:before` CSS style?

No libraries. Pure Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. For the reference -

 http://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element
http://pankajparashar.com/posts/modify-pseudo-elements-css/

Your css is like this

```
#image-container:before {
   background: url(img.png);
   content: '';
   position: fixed;
   z-index: -1;
   display: block;
   height: 40%;
}
```

Below is js to get background

```
var color = window.getComputedStyle(
  document.querySelector('#image-container'), ':before'
).getPropertyValue('color')
```

And to set the new css property

```
var style = document.createElement("style");

// Append the style tag to head
document.head.appendChild(style);

// Grab the stylesheet object
sheet = style.sheet

// Use addRule or insertRule to inject styles
sheet.addRule('#image-container::before','color: green');
sheet.insertRule('#image-container::before { color: green }', 0);
```

Comment: This answer shows how to access and retrieve the value in the `:before` style. How would I change the value? Also not talked about in your link.